# Fantasy book about a priest/cleric of the sun in a world where the sun is fading

Tags: story-identification, books

The main character was a cleric or priest of a religion which worshipped either fire generally or the sun specifically.  He was losing his faith because the sun was gradually getting dimmer, but there's a scene where he meets a salamander in a cave and his faith is restored (I believe he gains more powerful fire magic at this point).

Other details I can remember are that he eventually travels to a city which is besieged, and I believe the villains were necromancers.  There is definitely at least one sequel I remember being advertised in the back of the book, so it may be part of a series.  I believe the sequel had something to do with finding a bronze statue in a labyrinth.

I read this book sometime before 2009, so that's the latest it could have been published, but I wouldn't be surprised if it came out in the 80s or 90s.  I've searched through several lists of official Dungeons and Dragons novels without finding this one, but it definitely uses a lot of D&D tropes.  I've also searched through lists of novels in the "Dying Earth" subgenre, but I haven't found the one I'm looking for, and I don't recall any science fiction elements in the story.

Comment: Well the grandaddy of them all, Jack Vance's stories about "The Dying Earth", actually inspired Gary Gygax in a lot of the original details of D&D, especially the magic system. There was [a 2008 tribute anthology](https://georgerrmartin.com/dying-earth-anthology-nears-completion/) by various authors; did you look in that?

Comment: I just downloaded that collection and skimmed through it, and I don't think any of them is the story I'm remembering.  I believe it was a full novel and not a short story.  Thank you, though, and I'll probably end up reading that anthology.